# How can I get my partial view alert to fire before the parent page is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view with a submit button on it.  I want to send an alert fire an alert when the button is clicked.  If I remove the line…

return false;

The page is submitted and the alert will fire after the page is submitted.  If I leave ‘return false’ in the if statement the page won’t submit the alert wont fire either.  How can I get my partial view alert to fire before the parent page is submitted?

Here’s my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {
    var selectedName = $("#selectAname");
    $("#sendMail").click(function () {
        if (selectedName.val() == "Worng Choice")
            alert("You need to select the correct name")
        return false;
    });


});
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: What do you mean by 'partial view'? Do you want to alert on wrong choice and it wouldn't submit the form or you want alert it anyway and submit after?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to fire an alert on wrong choice and cancel submitting the form, you need to move `return false` into block with if (wrong choice):

```
$(function () {
    var selectedName = $("#selectAname");
    $("#sendMail").click(function () {
        if (selectedName.val() == "Worng Choice") {
            alert("You need to select the correct name");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Let's assume that I don't have a return false or even an if statement.  I simply want to fire an alert when I click the button.  My problem is the that the page gets submitted before the child's (my partial view) javascript runs.

Comment: So you want to submit anyway?

Comment: Eventually I want to prevent submission based on some value.  But right now I'm trying to figure out why would it wait until the parent page returns before the alert appears.  If I can get the alert to appear before the page is submitted then I will but the conditional statement in.

Comment: So you have an iframe or frame?

Comment: No sorry I've never used an iFrame.  Can you please point me to a tutorial that uses iFrame to address the problem?